# navigationBarItems "Type [view] cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to apply some navigationBarItems to my View and I've gotten this error - `Type '() -> Text' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols`

I've been able to dumb the code down to this. Anyone know what could be causing it?

```
struct NewEntry: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello World")
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: {
                Text("Hello World")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.navigationBarItems(trailing:)` takes a `View`.
You are providing the `View` inside `{}`

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: {
    Text("Hello World")
})
```

#### Solution:

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: Text("Hello, World"))
```

---

`SwiftUI`'s compiler is a bit dumb, small syntax mistakes causes it to throw weird errors at weird places.

Comment: Thanks for that. I got used to using the bracket syntax for similar stuff but didn't know it wasn't applicable to the navigationBarItems

Comment: @ChristianCamaisa it depends on the implementation. the curly brace that you say you have gotten used to are called `trailing closures`. In this case they look like `() -> _`. For example compare the function signature of `NavigationView(content: () -> _)` with `.navigationBarItems(trailing: View)`